# Rails Passenger/Capistrano/ubuntu App not serving assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, passenger, assets

After changing css files I did a rake assets:precompile and pushed it up to git. Then did a new deploy with capistrano to my server. Now none of my assets or styles are showing up on my page http://162.243.102.157/.
The assets are on the production deployment server, but I can't seem to figure out why either passenger or Rails isn't serving and showing the assets to my website...?

My ruby -v is:
2.2.3p173

Rails -v:
4.2.5.2

## capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
# If you are using rbenv add these lines:
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.3'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/setup'
#require 'capistrano/deploy'
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
#require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
#require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

## Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'

gem 'rake', '~> 10.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# gem 'pg'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.2'

# Use Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
# Use Font-Awesome
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
# Sprockets
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.8'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use Autoprefixer
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

#gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.3.4'

# Mail Forms
gem 'mail_form', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
gem 'sendgrid'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use PUMA
gem 'puma'

# Use Passenger as the app server
gem 'passenger'

# Use Devise for security
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.6'
# Use figaro for environment variables (aka. passwords)
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'

group :assets do
    gem 'compass-rails'
    # Add any compass extensions here
end


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'capistrano-figaro-yml', '~> 1.0.2'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production, :staging do

# Use Capistrano for deployment
  gem 'capistrano',  '~> 3.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0.4'
  # postgress
  #gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

## environments/production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  #config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  # Bad email addresses and raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port => 587,
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USER'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASS'],
    :domain => "domain.com",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

## config/deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4'

set :application, 'MyApplication'

set :user, 'user'

set :assets_roles, [:web, :app]
set :keep_assets, 2

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:CoreyVincent/HydraWeb.git'

set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/home/user/MyApplication'

set :rails_env, "production"

# set :deploy_via, :copy

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true
# set :use_sudo, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

#set :assets_prefix, ""

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

## Update:

Assets and styles are now showing up, but I can't seem to update anything. Now when I git push and deploy, the assets don't update to the new changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `config.serve_static_files` setting to true or make your web server serve these files.
I use Nginx (along with passenger) with this config :

```
server {
 ...
 passenger_enabled on;
 ...
 location ~* ^/assets/ {
   expires 1y;
   add_header Cache-Control public;
   add_header Last-Modified "";
   add_header ETag "";
   break;
 }
}
```

Comment: I have the 'passenger_enabled on;' setting already on. And I added those other lines that you have there, but that didn't do anything for me... @standelaune

Comment: Started working after I took your code back out and deployed again. Not sure what fixed it...

Comment: Though it is showing the assets now, I can't seem to update anything. When I push to git and then deploy, nothing is updating to the new changes...

Comment: This is another problem. Clear your browser's cache and reload. If it's not ok, check the javascript. I can't see anything weird in your config, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I had tried the browser cache clearing and reloading. Very odd... @standelaune